# Disable tap to click in xubuntu

Tags: touchpad, xubuntu

What is the "preferred" method to turn off tap to click in Xubuntu 9.10? It's not available in Settings->Mouse the way it is in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no touchpad manager coming by default in xubuntu. You have two choices (both of them in the standard repos, at least until Karmic Koala)

- [gsynaptics](http://gsynaptics.sourceforge.jp/): is a legacy utility that will be dropped sometime in the near future. There are no dependencies for this package.
- [GPointingDeviceSettings](http://live.gnome.org/GPointingDeviceSettings): this is the new utility that is going to be supported in future versions. Despite the fact this second option is gnome-oriented (check the link!), it has only one dependency (also in the repos), and it allows you to set up other pointing devices as well.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks. GPointingDevice was probably the best way to do this - I wish there was a way to turn off tap to click without turning off the touchpad scroll.

Comment: pushing the tapping time sliders all the way to the short end seems to disable taps without impacting scroll

Comment: http://live.gnome.org/GPointingDeviceSettings tells "This page does not exist yet."

Comment: gsynaptics is not available in repos for current Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple solution for this, at least for Xubuntu 10.04.
To try if this will work in another version, open the terminal and run the command `synclient MaxTapTime=0` 
Now test if the tap-to-click is disabled.
If it works do the following:

Open the Settings Manager for XFCE and then choose Sessions and Startup.
Open the tab Startup Programs.
Add a new, and set the command to `synclient MaxTapTime=0` 
It's case sensitive so be sure to write the command exactly as above.
Now you only need to restart, and your done!

Comment: if you want to use the command line you can just add `synclient MaxTapTime=0` to your `.profile`

Comment: Worked for me, thanks guys.  This has been bugging me for ages :)

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me on a Toshiba laptop (Fedora20) to **enable** the tap-to-click feature was to create a file like `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-enable-taps.conf` containing the lines

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "tap-by-default"
   MatchIsTouchpad "on"
   Option "TapButton1" "1"
EndSection
```

Conversely, to **disable** the tap-to-click feature I'd think that if, for some reason, no other options work--as is the case with GUI applications sometimes--you'd be able to create a file like `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-disable-taps.conf` changing the **Option "TabButton1" "1"** to **Option "TabButton1" "0"**

**Note**
This workaround is outlined on [fedorasolved.org](http://fedorasolved.org/Members/khaytsus/configuring-synaptics-using-hal)